# Store splitting words into array while reading a file bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have a file that contains multiple words with commas. I want to read a file and store these words into array. In this file, first line is header, the other lines are datum. But some datum are null.So, this null characters need to be 0 For instance;

```
H1;H2;H3;H4   
12;23;33;44   
44;;7;8   
13;;;9
```

So I want to skip first line and put datum into 4 array=>

```
H1 array= 12;44;13  
H2 array= 23;0;0  
H3 array= 33;7;0  
H4 array= 44;8;9
```

So my code is like that:

```
array=()
awk 'NR>1' $filename2 | while read line
do
    cntr=0
    IFS=";"
    for i in $line; do
        if [ -z $i ]; then array[cntr]=0; 
           else array[cntr]=$i;
        fi
    cntr=$[$cntr +1]
    done
    h1array+=("${array[0]}")
    h2array+=("${array[1]}")
    h3array+=("${array[2]}")
    h4array+=("${array[3]}")
done
for ((i=0;i<3;i++)); do
    echo "${h1array[$i]}"
done
for ((i=0;i<3;i++)); do
    echo "${h2array[$i]}"
done
for ((i=0;i<3;i++)); do
    echo "${h3array[$i]}"
done
for ((i=0;i<3;i++)); do
    echo "${h4array[$i]}"
done
```

So,it prints null in terminal. How can I do this? Thank you

Comment: So, what you *actually* want to do is fill empty records with `0`?

Comment: Yeah and add this values into array with 0

Comment: You don't need an array for this. You don't even need `bash`, you can do this in one line of `awk`. What is it that you are really trying to achieve (the problem you are trying to solve)?

Comment: I will use these datum later. So I need to store these datum into array. I have used awk, but it didn't work again

Comment: Also, `cntr=$[$cntr +1]` syntax is getting obsoleted, AFAIK. I would recommend using `cntr=$((cntr +1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
        [[ "${line}" == *';'* ]] || continue
        IFS=';' read -r h1 h2 h3 h4 <<< "${line}"
        h1array+=("${h1:-0}")
        h2array+=("${h2:-0}")
        h3array+=("${h3:-0}")
        h4array+=("${h4:-0}")
done < <(tail -n +2 input.txt)

echo "h1array = ${h1array[@]}"
echo "h2array = ${h2array[@]}"
echo "h3array = ${h3array[@]}"
echo "h4array = ${h4array[@]}"
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
h1array = 12 44 13
h2array = 23 0 0
h3array = 33 7 0
h4array = 44 8 9
```

Comment: Just to explain: `awk 'NR>1' $filename2 | while read ` spawns a sub-shell & the arrays are created/populated in that subshell.

Comment: ok,I have put space at the end of file :) thank you very much. it works now :)

Comment: I adapted the solution to just skip over lines which do not contain `;` instead which is more robust :-)

Comment: One further improvement: rather than using `tail`, you can use a compound command which reads and ignores the first line of the input before running the `while` loop: `{ read -r; while read -r line; do ...; done; } < input.txt`.

Comment: @chepner You are right, that's cleaner and gets rid of the process substitution.